# running an eclipse project via terminal

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, jar, terminal

I've seen through the net that I should use the command java -jar, followed by the project name in order to RUN my eclipse project. Can someone please explain how does it work- where should the code which would unzip the project-be wrriten? somewhere it should be written to take the args the user write in the command line and analyze them. How does it all combine together?
Any explanation would be appriciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What sort of Eclipse project? A simple Java program? An Eclipse rich client? An Eclipse headless app? Something else?

Comment: The project has a GUI side to config tasks to be auto-run later(this is written as simple eclipse program). Its second "side" is the apply- the possibility of applying the earlier chosen tasks. This should be done only by typing in terminal the project name and a config name-key to be autorun.(no GUI at all at this point)
Where should the code which analyzes the terminal command be written and manipulated? **What** makes the link between the user input command in terminal and the java (supposed to be) analyzer-project, that would properly  run the test given as args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I got the answer..
in order to run the project this way, I need to write a new project and get the arguments from the main. all functionality corresponding the task of "running from command line"  would be in that main function.